# Color specific text in a String

Tags: java, android

I want to color specific words in a string.
At the moment I am using this:

```
   SpannableString txt = new SpannableString(txt.toString());
    Pattern color = Pattern.compile("My Text");
    Matcher mat = color.matcher(txt);
    while(mat.find()) {
        txtt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), mat.start(), mat.end(), 0);
    }
```

This is working perfect for one text.. but the problem is that I want color more than one piece of text in differed colors.
I already tried it with:

```
    line = line.replace("My Text",
        "<font color='#0000ff'>" + "$0" + "</font>");
```

But StringBuilder seems not to work with this

```
textViewTs.setText(Html.fromHtml(line));
```

**UPDATE:**

if i try to continue the while loop like this

```
 SpannableString txtt = new SpannableString(txt.toString());
    Pattern color = Pattern.compile("first text");
    Matcher mat = color.matcher(txt);

    Pattern color2 = Pattern.compile("second text");
    Matcher mat2 = color2.matcher(txt);

    while(mat.find()) {
        txtt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), mat.start(), mat.end(), 0);
    } while(mat2.find()) {
        txtt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), mat.start(), mat.end(), 0);
    }
    textViewTs.setText(txtt);
```

I get a error that reads `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far`

Any good way to solve this?

Comment: How StringBuilder doesn't seems to work?

Comment: i didn't understand whats wrong with setSpan?

Comment: @pskink The problem is that i can't color more than one line of text in different colors

Comment: "But StringBuilder seems not to work" that is not a problem description. We need to know what exactly makes you think that it doesn't work, like what you expected, and what you got instead. I suspect that problem may be usage `replace` instead of `replaceAll` (this one uses regex) may be cause of your problem, but I am not sure if this is the only problem you are facing.

Comment: but you are using one color:  Color.BLUE, so change the color on every while loop iteration

Comment: @Pshemo Html.fromHtml cannot be applied to Java.lang.StringBuilder. That i have to replace `replace` with `replaceAll` is true, but that didn't fix my problem that Html.fromHtml cannot be applied to Java.lang.StringBuilder

Comment: please don't use crappy Html.fromHtml, your original solution is much much better

Comment: in second while replace mat.start(), mat.end() with mat2

Comment: try with the replace() method from the SpannableStringBuilder (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) instead of using the setSpan().

Comment: @pskink That was the problem! Thank you it works now fine :)

Comment: and use setSpan,  not crappy fromHtml...

Answer (score 0):

try with the replace() method from the SpannableStringBuilder (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) instead of using the setSpan().

Answer (score 0):

I have something perfect for you! I wrote some code and uploaded it to my website. You can find the page with intrsuctions on how to use it [here](http://vediogames.net/?page_id=89) and the code to add to your src folder [here](http://vediogames.net/javacode/ColorText.java).

I made this for LibGDX but it should work the same. All you need to do is change the code to change the color of the text and the code to draw the text! For example, if your using SurfaceView you could replace this:

```
if(character == 'r'){
    font.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

with this:

```
if(character == 'r'){
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Just an example, I don't thinks that's what your using, right? Just change it however you need it.

**How it Works:**
To change the color just add codes to the string you want to draw. For example, just say you want to draw "Hello World!" with "Hello" in red and "World" in blue at coordinates 50, 40 just run this:

```
ColorText.draw("&rHello &bWorld!", 1, batch, 50, 40);
```

Note! You will have to do a lot of finetuning for this to work for you but the basic code is there for handling the string.